# Crystal Report multiple subreports

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I need to display multiple subreports on first page then continue printing on next page

I have 2 subreports that I displayed in separate detail sections in my crystal report.
I want both to be displayed in the first page and continued on the next pages.
For example: 
Subreport 1 have 8 records
Subreport 2 have 15 records

In page 1
Subreport 1 will display first 5 records
Subreport 2 will display first 5 records

In page 2
Subreport 1 will display records 6-8
Subreport 2 will display records 6-10

In page 3
Subreport 1 will be empty since all records have been printed already
Subreport 2 will display records 10-15

Comment: try using a formula in newpageafter. Goto your subreport -> Go to section Expert of Details -> Select Paging Tab from above -> New Page After.... You can write a formula or can use visible records to 5. This will only show 5 records in one page and changes the page. Do the same in both of your subreports. I've never tried such thing but I guess it might help.

Comment: Create groups of 5's in the main report. Identity them. Then use the group identity to filter the subreport (as subreport link). Then break page in group footer. You will need to change the datasource or use formulas. Show your schema and i may help you more.